# Hotspot enabled computers in domain

Tags: powershell, windows-10

How can i get information about "Hotspot enabled" computers in my domain? May be from Powershell we can do it? Or some article about it?

I didnt found any keys about windows 10 "Mobile Hotspot Feauture"

Answer (score 1):

I got something you might like. You are going to need to be able to remote PS.

```
$username = "domain\administrator"
$password = "Your password"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter *
foreach($computer in $computers){
    $computerDNS = $computer.DNSHostName
    $hotspot = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerDNS -credential $credential -scriptblock {
        $hotspot = Get-Service "icssvc"
        if($hotspot.Status -eq "Running"){
            Write-Host "Hotspot is turned on on $env:computername" -ForegroundColor Red
            try{
                Start-Service "icssvc"
                Write-Host "Successfully stopped service on $env:computername" -ForegroundColor Green
            }catch{
                Write-Host "Unable to stop service on $env:computername" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }else{
            Write-Host "No Hotspot running on $env:computername" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
```

If it finds a running hotspot, it disables the hotspot and notifies you foreach computer in the array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it seems works.Thanks for respond, but how can i include all computers in domain to this script?

Comment: Hi Mirjeyhun, I've edited the script so it checks for every pc in your domain! I hope this helps you

Comment: it returns error - "This operation might require other privileges". But i am running this script under domain admin credentials...

Comment: You have insufficient rights. Checkout Windows Service Manager and make sure you are able to start/stop services. There is a lot to find about that subject if you Google the error.